# Aside from the Stratolaunch, how many other aircraft have split bodies?

Tags: aircraft-design, airframe, stratolaunch

So there's a lot of excitement about the new (and massive) Stratolaunch

[image]

Split bodies are uncommon (although launching spacecraft from them commercially is a new thing). The only other airframe that I've seen like this would be [Virgin's White Knight 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_White_Knight_Two) (also a spacecraft launcher). Do any other aircraft use a split body like this?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12963/62)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on how you define it but there have been a variety over the years:

- The [P-38 Lighting has 3 bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-38_Lightning) there was also a later experimental [version the XP-49](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_XP-49) that only saw a single airframe.
- The [F-82 was a a twin fuselage version of the P-51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_F-82_Twin_Mustang)
- [The boomerang](http://rutanboomerang.com/) which was also designed by Burt Rutan (the designer of the stratolaunch)
- [A one off twin fuselage piper cub was built](http://www.fiddlersgreen.net/models/aircraft/Piper-TwinCub.html) but never saw production scale.
- As @DanPichelman points out in the comments, [the Yak-110](http://inspire.eaa.org/2017/11/30/because-they-could/)

> ...although launching spacecraft from them commercially is a new thing

This is not entirely true, piggy backing rocket planes on larger aircraft has [been widely done since the 50's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX8CkyDzPN0)

Comment: The [Yak-110](http://inspire.eaa.org/2017/11/30/because-they-could/) also comes to mind.

Comment: Don't forget the He 111Z

Comment: Don't forget the baffling arrangement of the BV-141 either

Comment: also, It's a tiny bit of a stretch but what about any of the AeroVironment craft? Their avionics were housed in several "pods" Then again maybe that plane had no body at all. Just a propellers and solar cells.